# fill edit text to the complete screen android

Tags: android

Hello
In my android application on click of image i would like to display a page which could provide a notepad facility to user.
I placed a edit text with fill parent but the cursor starts from the middle of the screen.
Is there any way that i can start the cursor from the beginning.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Can you post your layout XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
android:gravity="top"
```

:)

Comment: @Remmyabhavan: please click the checkmark to the left of this answer if it worked